# There is a way to get the return value from jQuery event?

Tags: jquery, anonymous-function

I have this code to validate if a field is empty or not. It is binded into the blur event of a input with an anonymous function.

```
isValidText = function(){        
    if ($(this).val().trim() == ""){
        //some code here
        return false;
    }
    //some code here
    return true;
}

$("#someElement").blur(isValidText);
```

At a certain point, I want to get the returning value from the binded function doing something like this:

```
//this return a jQuery object
var isValid = $("#someElement").blur(); 
//but I want the boolean from the isValidText
```

This is not possible because the `blur()` method return a jQuery object and not the return value of the `isValidText` function.

My question here is if there is a way to get the return value from the `isValidText` binded inside the blur event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#someElement").blur(function() {
   var ret = isValidText.call(this); 
});
```

OR

```
$("#someElement").blur(function() {
   var ret = isValidText.apply(this, arguments); // if you work with some hadler
});
```

Comment: you need to use apply/call to set what `this` is in the isValidText method: `var ret = isValidText.call(this);` and use ret outside the blur to check what ret is for value further down in the code.

Comment: `isValidText.apply( this, arguments );` would be more accurate and could work with any kind of handler

Comment: I used the apply method passing the field I want to validate without the need of calling the blur method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use thecodeparadox solution, or you could add a HTML5 data attribute on your #someElement and look into that:

```
isValidText = function(){ 
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data("isValid", !($this.val().trim() === ""));
}
$("#someElement").blur(isValidText);

/* Further down when you want to check if its valid or not */
if(!$("#someElement").data("isValid")) { 
   alert('someElement is not valid!') ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this

```
var isValid;

isValidText = function(valueToCheck){        
    if ($.trim(valueToCheck) == ""){
        //some code here
        return false;
    }
    //some code here
    return true;
}

$("#someElement").on('blur', function() {
    isValid=isValidText(this.value);
    //or just : 
    if (isValidText(this.value)) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/MpkPg/)